# How to get my clients to chat with eachother using one server PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am currently working on a python chatroom using UDP and have been struggling to get my clients to send messages with each other. I don't really know what to. Should I be using threading?

clientcode.py

```
From socket import *
print ("Welcome")
nameclient = input ("Enter Name:")
clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
serverName = '0.0.0.0'
serverPort = 54342
while True:
   message = input ("Enter message:")
   clientSocket.sendto(message.encode(),(serverName, serverPort))
   modifiedMessage, serverAddress = clientSocket.recvfrom(2048)
   clientSocket.close()
```

servercode.py

```
from socket import *

serverPort = 54342
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)

serverSocket.bind(('0.0.0.0', serverPort))


print ("Connecting............")
while True :
   message, clientAddress = serverSocket.recvfrom(2048)
   print("Recieved connection from: ", clientAddress)
   modifiedMessage = message.decode().upper()
   print (message)

   serverSocket.sendto(modifiedMessage.encode(), clientAddress)

   if message == ('STOP'):
        break
```

Comment: threading is a good idea

Comment: normally I would use `TCP` instead of `UDP` to makes sure client is still connected and I have to send message. And then server have to run every client in seprated `threads`. You can find many examples for this not only in Python but also in C. But I don't know how to do this with UDP. If client close connection and it doesn't wait for new information then I don't how it could get information from other user. Probably for every user you would have to keep new messages in dictionary - ie `{clientAddress: [List with message waiting for sending]}` and send them when it connect again.